# Save list of image or background image in momgodb with mongoose and retrive as selection of image input to be attached on user post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am working on a MERN project, trying to add additional features, 
I want to have a selection input image list stored in advance inside `MongoDB` displayed on close to the photo camera icon which is the main photo input icon so that the user can choose an extra image from the selection and add on his post before clicking on post button.

the result will show the `2images` and on the text and only one image if the user did not pick the extra image on the selection

[Refer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAbFT.jpg)

Here is the post-model Schema

```
 import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import crypto from 'crypto'
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Name is required'
  },
  photo: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  },
  ribbon:[
    {
    ribbon1: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon2: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon3: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon4: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon5: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon6: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon7: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon8: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon9: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },
    ribbon10: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String
    },

  }

  ] ,

  likes: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  comments: [{
    text: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
  }],
  postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },



})

export default mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)
```

Comment: Did you already write some Code? If so please share a minimal example with us so we can figure out what your problem is.

Comment: Yes I just add the post model schema where ribbon is the array of image list I want that user can select.. I was trying to it as I did with the pictures that the user uploaded but not sure if is the best way to handle it